# How to structure code for a component that changes content on route change, but should not unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Say I have the following structure:

```
  <Router>
    <Sidebar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
      <Route path='/reports' component={Reports} />
      <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Sidebar shows up on the left, the rest on the right. Sidebar allows to jump from page to page. Additionally, I want each page (home, reports, products) to have a top menu that changes its contents depending on the page I'm on. But it should not disappear (for a fraction of a second) when I'm changing the pages using sidebar. It's always gonna have the same styles, only text/contents might change.

What's the best way to implement it? If I put menu in every page separately I think it's gonna disappear for a moment when I'm changing pages (because it needs to unmount one instance and mount another). If, on the other hand, I put it outside of the 3 routs completely, i.e. next to the Sidebar, then it's gonna be troublesome to keep menu and pages logic (methods, props etc.) in 2 different components - they are after all, conceptually, part of the same view, and it would be nice to have the logic in the same component.

Comment: You have to create layouts with header, side bar

Comment: you can make a layout of your web application and with `redux` change values in top menu depending of page you are in.

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-multiple-layout-d5yfw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

If a set of routes share the same layout, you might consider creating a separate router component for these routes.

```
const MenuLayout = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/reports' component={Reports} />
        <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

If you need to connect the `<Menu />` component with these routes, you can also use the Route `render` prop to inject props from the router component.

```
<Route path="/" render={props => <Home {...props} customProps={true} />} exact />
```

I've also been using a custom `Route` component which accepts a `layout` prop. This `layout` prop is a component that contains the NavBar and Footer. Using this method, the routes stay in a single file.

```
import { Route as ReactRouterRoute, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const CleanLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {children}
  </React.Fragment>
);

const MenuLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Menu />
    {children}
  </React.Fragment>
);

const Route = ({ component: Component, layout, ...rest }) => {
  const Layout = layout || CleanLayout;

  return (
    <ReactRouterRoute
      {...rest}
      render={props => (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Layout>
      )}
    />
  );
};

const MenuLayout = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} layout={MenuLayout} />
        <Route path='/reports' component={Reports} layout={MenuLayout} />
        <Route path='/products' component={Products} layout={MenuLayout} />
        <Route path='/onboard' component={Onboard} layout={CleanLayout} />
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: But when user switches from /reports to /products doesn't one instance of the Menu unmount and the other mounts? In that case, wouldn't it disappear for a fraction of a second?

Comment: No, since the layout component doesn't change, React reuses the [same component](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).